# self similar solution for porous medium equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

firstly

what does the in-variance under the scaling transformation mean ?

secondly

let $u$ be a function invariant under the scaling transformation $$u_k(x,t)=k^nu(kx,k^{2+(m-1)n}t)$$ $k>0$

such that $$u_k(x,t)=u(x,t)$$ $x\in R^n$ ,$t>0$ , $k>0$ is satisfied .

then he said $u$ can be expressed by $$u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$$ with $w(y)=u(y,1)$ $y\in R^n$ $k=t^{-l/n}$ $l=\frac{n}{2+(m-1)n}$

where did the the expression come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invariance of an equation with respect a transformation (or more generally a group of transformations) meas that if $u$ is a solution of the equation and $v$ is the *scaled* solution (i.e., $u$ subject to he transformation) then $v$ is also a solution.

In the example you give, it would mean that if $u$ is a solution, then $u_k$ is also a solution. The solution $u$ is called self-similar if $u_k=u$ for all $k$. This type of solution s important for several reasons, among them:

- Sometimes can be obtained explkiciteky
- Often they represent a generic behavior of the solutions, for instance, the asymptotic behavior.

As for your last question, set $k=t^{-l/n}$, where $l$ is a constant to be determined. Then
\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=k^n\,u(k\,x,k^{2+(m-1)n}t)\\
&=t^{-l}\,u(t^{-l/n}\,x,t^{-2l/n-l(m-1)+1}).
\end{align}
Now choose $l$ so that $-2\,l/n-l\,(m-1)+1=0$.

Comment: okay sir could you help me again    then he said a function $u$ invariant under the scaling transformation $$u_k(x,t)=k^nu(kx,k^{2+(m-1)n}t)$$ $k>0$ is a solution of $$\partial_tu-\Delta u^m=0$$ if and only is $w$ satisfies $$\Delta w^m(y)+\frac{l}{n}<y,\nabla w(y)>+lw(y)=0$$ $y\in R^n$ 

How ??????

Comment: This is a new question, not a comment.

Comment: okay sir https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337953/self-similar-solution-for-porous-medium-equation-2 please help me