# self similar solution for porous medium equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

let $u$ be a function invariant under the scaling transformation $$u_k(x,t)=k^nu(kx,k^{2+(m-1)n}t)$$ $k>0$

such that $$u_k(x,t)=u(x,t)$$ $x\in R^n$ ,$t>0$ , $k>0$ is satisfied .

then$u$ can be expressed by $$u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$$ with $w(y)=u(y,1)$ $y\in R^n$ $k=t^{-l/n}$ $l=\frac{n}{2+(m-1)n}$

how can we prove that $u$ is a solution of $$\partial_t u-\Delta u^m=0$$ if and only if $w$ satisfies $$\Delta w^n(y)+\frac{l}{n}<y,\nabla w(y)>+lw(y)=0$$ where $y\in R^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is substitute $u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$ in the equation and obtain the equation for $w$. For this you have to compute the derivatives of $u$ in terms of the derivatives of $w$.

Comment: I've tried many time but i couldn't manage to obtain this equation sir

Comment: could you help me please sir ?

Comment: could you help me please sir ?

Comment: how can we calculate $\partial_t u$ and $\Delta u^m$

Comment: please sir help me

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338053/self-similar-solution-for-porous-medium-equation-3

Comment: please tell me how you computed  the derivatives of $u$ in terms of the derivatives of $w$  how you computed $\partial_t u$ and $\Delta u^m$

Comment: could you see the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338994/self-similar-solution-for-porous-medium-equation-3

Comment: could you see the following link please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339594/barenblatt-self-similar-solution