# i need help please help me nonlinear partial differential equations

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, proof-explanation

let  $$u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$$ where $w(y)=u(y,1)$ $y\in R^n$ $k=t^{-l/n}$ $l=\frac{n}{2+(m-1)n}$

prove that $u$ is a solution of $$\partial_t u-\Delta u^m=0$$ if and only if $w$ satisfies $$\Delta w^m(y)+\frac{l}{n}<y,\nabla w(y)>+lw(y)=0$$ where $y\in R^n$

Comment: Please edit your question title to something useful.

Comment: @SeanRoberson could you help me here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338994/self-similar-solution-for-porous-medium-equation-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$,

that $\partial_t u-\Delta u^m=0\tag 1$

and that $l=\dfrac{n}{2+(m-1)n}$ or $-lm-2l/n=-l-1\tag 2$

Computing the partial wrt $t$

$\partial_tu=-lt^{-l-1}w(y)-t^{-l}(l/n)\langle t^{-l/n-1}x,\nabla w(y)\rangle=$

$=-t^{-l-1}\left(lw(y)+(l/n)\langle t^{-l/n}x,\nabla w(y)\rangle\right)=$

$=-t^{-l-1}\left(lw(y)+(l/n)\langle y,\nabla w(y)\rangle\right)$

We are working in fact with the laplacian applied to two different functions, $u(x,t)$ and $w(y)$. For the first,

$$\Delta u(x,t)=\sum_1^n\partial_{x_ix_i}u$$

and for the second,

$$\Delta w(y)=\sum_1^n\partial_{y_iy_i}u$$

We have too, $\partial_{x_i} y_i=t^{-l/n}\;;i=1,\cdots,n$ With these considerations, we can calculate the laplacian for $u^m$

$$\partial_{x_ix_i} u^m=\partial_{x_i}(\partial_{x_i}t^{-lm}w^m)=$$

$$=t^{-lm}\partial_{x_i}(mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_i}w\partial_{x_i}y_i)=t^{-lm}t^{-l/n}\partial_{x_i}(mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_i}w)=$$

$$=t^{-lm-l/n}(mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w\partial_{x_i}y_i+m(m-1)w^{m-2}(\partial_{y_iy_i}w)^2\partial_{x_i}y_i)=$$

$$=t^{-lm-l/n}(t^{-l/n}mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w+t^{-l/n}m(m-1)w^{m-2}(\partial_{y_iy_i}w)^2)=$$

$$=t^{-lm-2l/n}(mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w+m(m-1)w^{m-2}(\partial_{y_iy_i}w)^2)=$$

$$\Delta u^m(x,t)=t^{-lm-2l/n}\sum_1^n(mw^{m-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w+m(m-1)w^{m-2}(\partial_{y_iy_i}w)^2)$$

Now the laplacian for $w^n$

$$\partial_{y_iy_i}w^n=\partial_{y_i}(\partial_{y_i}w^n)=\partial_{y_i}(nw^{n-1}\partial_{y_i}w)=$$

$$=nw^{n-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w+n(n-1)w^{n-2}(\partial_{y_i}w)^2$$

$$\Delta w^n=\sum_1^n(nw^{n-1}\partial_{y_iy_i}w+n(n-1)w^{n-2}(\partial_{y_i}w)^2)$$

The relation between the laplacians is, taking into account $(2)$,

$$\Delta u^m=t^{-tm-2t/n}\Delta w^m=t^{-l-1}\Delta w^m$$

Putting all in $(1)$ we get the identity,

$$\partial_tu-\Delta u^m=-t^{-l-1}\left(lw(y)+(l/n)\langle y,\nabla w(y)\rangle\right)-t^{-l-1}\Delta w^m=0$$

Or,

$$lw(y)+(l/n)\langle y,\nabla w(y)\rangle+\Delta w^m=0$$

I couldn't prove the assertion because the exponent is $m$ and not $n$. Nevertheles, I think it's false and the assertion holds with $m$ instead of $n$ for the exponent.

Comment: which assertion did you mean ?

Comment: Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations: Asymptotic Behavior of Solutions and Self-Similar Solutions
author(s) Mi-Ho Giga, Yoshikazu Giga, Jürgen Saal page 107

Comment: yes it is $m$ not $n$ it was a mistake in writing

Comment: Ok, then, the assertion is proved. :)

Comment: do you have email i would like to be in touch with you

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's the format of open dialogue what I like of this site. I'm glad, anyway :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338994/self-similar-solution-for-porous-medium-equation-3 could you help me here sir please ?

Comment: could you see the following link please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339594/barenblatt-self-similar-solution