# self similar solution for porous medium equation 3

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, proof-explanation

let  $$u(x,t)=t^{-l}w(t^{-l/n}x)$$ where $w(y)=u(y,1)$ $y\in R^n$ $k=t^{-l/n}$ $l=\frac{n}{2+(m-1)n}$

we know that  $u$ is a solution of $$\partial_t u-\Delta u^m=0$$ if and only if $w$ satisfies $$\Delta w^m(y)+\frac{l}{n}<y,\nabla w(y)>+lw(y)=0$$ where $y\in R^n$

then we shall choose the pressure $v=w^{m-1}$ and if $v>0$ from the previous equation we obtain :
$$v^{\frac{1}{m-1}}\frac{m}{m-1}[\Delta v+\frac{1}{m-1}|\nabla v|^2 v^{-1}+\frac{l}{mn}v^{-1}<y,\nabla v>+\frac{l(m-1)}{m}]=0$$

how does this happen ?